# Permisos correctos de sitio wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permisos

Por un problema en el sitio, cambié los permisos de todas las carpetas y archivos de mi sitio de forma recursiva, de acuerdo a este [tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Shared_Hosting_with_suexec). Como tengo un hosting compartido que usa suexec, coloqué 775 a todas las carpetas, y 644 a todos los archivos (excepto wp-config.php), el problema es que ahora el sitio no funciona, me larga el error HTTP ERROR 500.

Alguna idea de como puedo arreglar esto? :S

Answer (score 1):

Los permisos correctos para los archivos de `Wordpress` son:

- `0644` para los niveles superiores, esto es la raíz del sitio y todos los ficheros que estén ahí situados.
- `0755` para las tres carpetas (wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes).
- `0755` para las carpetas uploads y plugins (En algunos casos 775, depende de configuración del servidor)
- `0666` para tu tema de WordPress en caso de que quieras que sea editable desde el escritorio.